# I am trying to design a program that compares two strings for the same character in the same positions but same error keeps popping up

Tags: java, eclipse, boolean, do-while

Length does not matter in this regard so for example:

```
string 1:    "hi--there-you."    "-15-389"    "criminal-plan"    "abc"

string 2:    "12--(134)-7539"    "-xy-zzy"    "(206)555-1384"    "9.8"
```

Both pairs would return True. My problem is that when I try to compile the code below I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at SameDashes.sameDashes(SameDashes.java:20)
    at SameDashes.main(SameDashes.java:4)
```

Here is my code:

```
   public static boolean sameDashes(String a, String b){
    int minlength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    String smallstring="";
    String bigstring="";
    if(a.length()== minlength){
        smallstring = a;
        bigstring = b;
    }
    else {
        smallstring = b;
        bigstring =a;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    do {
        if(bigstring.charAt(smallstring.indexOf('-',counter))!='-'){
            return false;
        }
        else if(bigstring.indexOf('-',counter)!= -1){
            return false;
        }
        counter++;

    }while(counter<= bigstring.length());
    return true;
}
```

The code works for some reason with some strings but not with others and I really do not understand why the same error is popping up.

Comment: I do not know how to tag this as homework but it is, help is appreciated!!

Comment: This site _explicitly_ states that it is not a place for homework. We aren't your slaves.

Comment: @AndrewL did you even look at it? I already did the work I just need help fixing one thing. I've seen a lot of homework questions answered here.

Comment: I looked at your comment, and so I wrote the comment. We don't take homework requests. Also, the answer is easily googleable, and the stacktrace is _very_ easy to understand.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)

Comment: Why do you say "we"? Are you the whole community? again I am not ordering anyone to help me I am simply asking for help there is no reason to try to hinder my work.

Comment: Please check this [URL] (http://stackoverflow.com/help) it'll be help you to raise your content quality

Comment: No problem with homework, maybe all you need to change is `while(counter<= bigstring.length());` to `while(counter< bigstring.length());`

Comment: @ScaryWombat sadly, didn't work. I usually can fix this kind of thing by myself but I am not very well versed when it comes to strings and how they work. My professor is not much help either (not his fault just the school doesn't care about computer science that much)

Comment: looking at it again, it seems that you should only be looping for the length of the small string, otherwise you will exceed the length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!!!!

```
    public static boolean sameDashes(String a, String b){
    int minlength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    String smallstring="";
    String bigstring="";
    if(a.length()== minlength){
        smallstring = a;
        bigstring = b;
    }
    else {
        smallstring = b;
        bigstring =a;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    do{     
        if(smallstring.equals(bigstring)){
            return true;
        }
        else if(smallstring.indexOf('-',counter)!= -1){
            y++;
            if(bigstring.charAt(smallstring.indexOf('-',counter))== '-'){
            }
        }
        if(bigstring.indexOf('-',counter)!=-1){
            x++;
        }
        counter++;
    }while(counter<=bigstring.length());
    if(y==x){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It may not be the most optimized code out there but hey, it works!

Answer (score -1):

Look at what smallString.indexOf('-', counter) will return after counter is greater than the last index of a '-'. Then look at the charAt documentation to see if that leads to any clarification.